# Magento 2 How to add required to Dob & Gender without use backend option

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm trying to create a new custom registration but not same the original one and i need to set Dob & Gender as required fields.

```
<?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob::class) ?>
<?php echo $_dob->setDate($block->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
<?php $_gender = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender::class) ?>
<?php echo $_gender->setGender($block->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make them required with the help of jQuery in your phtml file where you have written this :

```
<?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob::class) ?>
<?php echo $_dob->setDate($block->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
<?php $_gender = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender::class) ?>
<?php echo $_gender->setGender($block->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?>
```

> jQuery('#dob').attr('data-validate','{required:true}');
>
> jQuery('#gender').attr('data-validate','{required:true}');

I am assuming you have included jQuery.